# Returning MIN Row_Number() SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is probably the clunkiest query I have ever made. I have to use a read-only account so I can't use temp tables or anything to make this easier. The goal is to return the `MIN(RowNum)` when `sumPiecesScrapped = maxSum`. I have tried adding the entire query into another subquery trying to return the `MIN(RowNum)` however, it is one-to-many that is tied to the primary key `JobNo` and when I tie it to `JobNo` and `StepNo` it gives me the same result as the one below.

```
SELECT
JobNo,
StepNo,
sumPiecesScrapped,
maxSum,
CASE
WHEN sumPiecesScrapped = maxSum THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobNo ORDER BY JobNo, StepNo)
ELSE 0
END AS RowNum
FROM
(
    SELECT
    JobNo,
    StepNo,
    sumPiecesScrapped
    FROM
    (   
            SELECT
            JobNo,
            StepNo,
            SUM(PiecesScrapped) as sumPiecesScrapped
            FROM
            (
                SELECT
                JobNo,
                StepNo,
                PiecesFinished,
                PiecesScrapped
                FROM TimeTicketDet
            ) tt2

            GROUP BY JobNo, StepNo
    ) tt3
    GROUP BY JobNo, StepNo, sumPiecesScrapped
) tt4

LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
    JobNo as tt5JobNo,
    MAX(PiecesScrapped) as maxSum
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
        JobNo,
        PiecesScrapped
        FROM TimeTicketDet
    ) tt5
    GROUP BY JobNo
) tt5
ON tt5.tt5JobNo = tt4.JobNo


WHERE tt4.JobNo = '12345'
```

**Result:**

```
+-------+--------+-------------------+--------+--------+
| JobNo | StepNo | sumPiecesScrapped | maxSum | RowNum |
+-------+--------+-------------------+--------+--------+
| 12345 |     10 |                 0 |      5 |      0 |
| 12345 |     20 |                 1 |      5 |      0 |
| 12345 |     30 |                 5 |      5 |      3 |
| 12345 |     40 |                 5 |      5 |      4 |
| 12345 |     60 |                 5 |      5 |      5 |
| 12345 |     70 |                 5 |      5 |      6 |
+-------+--------+-------------------+--------+--------+
```

**Desired Result:**

```
+-------+--------+-------------------+--------+--------+
| JobNo | StepNo | sumPiecesScrapped | maxSum | RowNum |
+-------+--------+-------------------+--------+--------+
| 12345 |     10 |                 0 |      5 |      0 |
| 12345 |     20 |                 1 |      5 |      0 |
| 12345 |     30 |                 5 |      5 |      3 |
| 12345 |     40 |                 5 |      5 |      3 |
| 12345 |     60 |                 5 |      5 |      3 |
| 12345 |     70 |                 5 |      5 |      3 |
+-------+--------+-------------------+--------+--------+
```

**Other Possible Result:**

```
+-------+--------+-------------------+--------+-----------+
| JobNo | StepNo | sumPiecesScrapped | maxSum |  RowNum   |
+-------+--------+-------------------+--------+-----------+
| 12345 |     10 |                 0 |      5 | 0         |
| 12345 |     20 |                 1 |      5 | 0         |
| 12345 |     30 |                 5 |      5 | Something |
| 12345 |     40 |                 5 |      5 | 0         |
| 12345 |     60 |                 5 |      5 | 0         |
| 12345 |     70 |                 5 |      5 | 0         |
+-------+--------+-------------------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Without some table definitions and clarity on what you are trying to accomplish I can't wrap my head around this. But MIN(Row_Number) would always be 1. :)

Comment: What do you mean you can't use temporary tables? Every user has access to `tempdb` you should still be able to make use of syntax like `CREATE TABLE #temp (someColumn varchar(10));` or (alternatively) a table variable.

Comment: @SeanLange In the TimeTicketDet table, JobNo is the primary key and there can be multiple steps per JobNo. I am trying to get SQL, without a cte, to figure out the first time sumPiecesScrapped = maxSum.

Comment: @Larnu Uhhhhh I was definitely under the impression that required write access. Let me go do some testing with that. I will feel so foolish if I tried all of these work arounds and I could use a tempdb.

Comment: Right....you want some help reworking this query. I get that. But we have nothing to work with. Posting the table definitions and sample data makes it so others can help. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great example.

Comment: Why without a CTE?   You definitely don't need write access for a CTE.

Comment: @TabAlleman Because I am going to take the finalized query and throw it into a master query that already contains a CTE.

Comment: You can have more than 1 CTE is a query though. `WITH CTE AS (SELECT 1 AS a),CTE2 AS (SELECT 1 AS b) SELECT a,b FROM CTE1, CTE2;`

Comment: @Larnu Thank you. Apparently I can use temp tables. That was a I hadn't had enough coffee mistake.